# UIDatePicker max and min date range

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I develop my own app and I work on sign up screen.The person who sign up my app have to enter a birth date in my textfield and only user has 18-55 age accept.My textField has UIDatePicker.When datePicker open ,I want to show min and max date range.For example today now 12/02/2022 , datePicker have to show min date 12/02/2004 (user has 18) and show max date 1/1/1967 (user has 55).[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkGbW.jpg

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Also. please [edit] your question to include your current code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s)? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried and where you are stuck would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Incidentally, I notice your `#available(İOS 13.4, *)` is written with the [Turkish letter `İ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%B0): `İOS`.  You *probably* want to use the [ASCII letter `I`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I) instead: `#available(IOS 13.4, *)`

Comment: @dbc Actually you want the ASCII letter `i` (lowercase) as in `iOS`, not `IOS`.

Answer (score 0):

first change the version checking line to

```
if #available(iOS 13.4,*) {

}
```

secondly use calendar for min max date

```
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        if let eighteenAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -18, to: Date()),
           let afterFiftyFive =  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 55, to: Date()) {
            print(eighteenAgo.formatted(), ": Min")
            print(afterFiftyFive.formatted(), ": Max")
            datePicker.minimumDate = eighteenAgo
            datePicker.maximumDate = afterFiftyFive
        }
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: write this code in viewwillappear (if let...

Comment: I wrote your code inside viewwillappear , print methods is working and ı can see what I wanted date in xcode debug area but it not loaded datepicker inside.

Comment: and wait until the wheel stops scrolling.. wheel re arrange itself to giving date range after stop scrolling.. you test this also by using .inline date picker

Comment: the wheel date picker is slow you just have able to scrolling to out of range but not selecting them wheel picker automatically took you inside range after stop scrolling

Comment: its not working unfortunately.how can ı  send you my codes?.actually ı don't change so much codes,ı only write your codes viewwillappear.

Comment: @Swiftniscate - you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74649032/edit) your question to share your code **in the question itself**, ideally as a [mcve] that fully demonstrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.